# Formatting - Algorithm

Tags: pseudocode

I have following pseudocode:

[image]

I want to write it as an algorithm but not able to format it properly. Following is my attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,amsmath,algpseudocode}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Adaptive Thresholding}\label{euclid}

  \begin{algorithmic}[1]

    \State Convert $R$ to a binary region using the threshold $\theta_{0}$. \label{step:convert}

    \State Assume $N$ is the sum of the number of non-zero pixels within $F_{l}$ and $F_{r}$.

    \State If $N$ is larger than a predefined threshold $\beta$, then
             \State $\theta_{0} = \theta_{0} + \Delta\theta$
             \State Repeat the procedure from step \ref{step:convert}
    \State Else
             \State $\theta = \theta_{0}$
    \State End
    \State where $\Delta\theta$, $\beta$ are two constants.

  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

and this is what I get:
[image]

Any ideas how to format lines 4-8? I have to show the pseudocode in algorithm format.

Comment: If you read the user guide of the algorithm package, you'll see that the `If Then Else` is properly defined as:
`\IF{condition 1}`
`\STATE procedure 1`
`\ELSIF{condition 2}`
`\STATE procedure 2`
`\ELSIF{condition 3}`
`\STATE procedure 3`
`\ELSE`
`\STATE procedure 4`
`\ENDIF`

Comment: @pluton could you please provide a working solution? I tried various ways already...

Comment: @pluton thanks. just an edit: All letters are not in caps. Instead of \IF \ELSE \ENDIF I tried \If \Else \EndIf and it worked. Wasn't working with caps.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in your code was that you did not call if-else as a command. If you fix this, then it solves your problem.

```
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Adaptive Thresholding}\label{euclid}

  \begin{algorithmic}[1]

    \State Convert $R$ to a binary region using the threshold $\theta_{0}$. \label{step:convert}

    \State Assume $N$ is the sum of the number of non-zero pixels within $F_{l}$ and $F_{r}$.

    \If{$N$ is larger than a predefined threshold $\beta$}
              \State $\theta_{0} = \theta_{0} + \Delta\theta$
              \State Repeat the procedure from step \ref{step:convert}
    \Else 
              \State $\theta = \theta_{0}$
    \EndIf
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}


Where $\Delta\theta$, $\beta$ are two constants.
```